# Access: Expression too complex to be evaluated - SUM Time Values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm doing a simple application with Access and I'm having the Query:

```
SELECT QryInOutMday.[_USERID], QryInOutMday.[_WORKING]
FROM QryInOutMday;
```

which is getting the next values without issues :

_USERID   _WORKING
--------        ---------
76              07:33:15
76              16:22:54
68              08:01:22
77              07:33:15
77              07:50:00

I'm trying to sum the working hours and to group them with the user id as following :

```
SELECT QryInOutMday.[_USERID], SUM(QryInOutMday.[_WORKING])
FROM QryInOutMday
GROUP BY QryInOutMday.[_USERID];
```

but i'm getting the error : Expression too complex to be evaluated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error means.  But the problem is that you cannot sum time values.  You can convert to a unit and then sum those:

```
SELECT iom.[_USERID],
       SUM(DATEDIFF("s", 0, iom.[_WORKING])) as total_seconds
FROM QryInOutMday as iom
GROUP BY iom.[_USERID];
```

You can use `format` is you like to get a format as hh:mm:ss:

```
SELECT iom.[_USERID],
       FORMAT(SUM(DATEDIFF("s", 0, iom.[_WORKING]))/(24*60*60),  "hh:mm:ss") as total_hhmmss
FROM QryInOutMday as iom
GROUP BY iom.[_USERID];
```

Comment: I have tried to calculate the hours and minutes each one alone as following:

SELECT QryInOutMday.[_USERID], COUNT(QryInOutMday.[_USERID]) AS _WorkingDays ,Int(SUM(DATEDIFF("h", 0, QryInOutMday.[_WORKING]))) as _WorkingHour, Int(SUM(DATEDIFF("n", 0, QryInOutMday.[_WORKING]))) as _WorkingMin
FROM QryInOutMday
GROUP BY QryInOutMday.[_USERID];

now i'm getting the hours as int "23" and min as int "1435" which minutes should be 1435-23*60 = "55" , how could i achive that ?

Comment: "you cannot sum time values" ... oh, you certainly can.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if [_WORKING] is *Date*. If it is *text*, first convert to Date:

```
SELECT QryInOutMday.[_USERID], SUM(CDate(QryInOutMday.[_WORKING]))
FROM QryInOutMday
GROUP BY QryInOutMday.[_USERID];
```

If *Null* values may exist, filter these out or use *CVDate*:

```
SELECT QryInOutMday.[_USERID], SUM(CVDate(QryInOutMday.[_WORKING]))
FROM QryInOutMday
GROUP BY QryInOutMday.[_USERID];
```

If the sum may exceed 24 hours, you can use this function for a read out the sum formatted like hours and minutes:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinute( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of datTime
' converted to hours and minutes as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03# + #20:01#
'   returns: 30:04
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String

  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute

  FormatHourMinute = strHourMinute

End Function
```